# Laravel jQuery loading twice

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I have a Laravel web application. I'm adding functionality through Javascript files. More in particular, I want some text fields to render as [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) input fields.

In app.blade.php, I have the following:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@yield('scripts');
```

In create.blade.php, I have a reference to the select2 js file and some custom js code.

```
@section('scripts')

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
   });
</script>

@endsection('scripts')
```

This results in

```
>     select2.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>     create:174 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I'm sure jQuery is loaded as it is defined in the bootstrap.js file as follows (and works for other functionality such as dropbox):

```
try {
    //window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery/dist/jquery.slim");
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    require("bootstrap");
} catch (e) {}
```

When I remove the app.js reference in app.blade.php (so this instance of jQuery is not loaded) and I manually add jQuery in the create.blade.php (so only one jQuery instance is loaded), everything works. See below:

app.blade.php

```
<!-- Scripts -->
@yield('scripts');
```

create.blade.php

```
@section('scripts')
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        });
    </script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/dropzone.js') }}" defer></script>

@endsection
```

If I do this, the input field renders as tags which is what I want. However this results in not being able to logout from Laravel app (because the app.js is removed).

How can I ensure that select2 works with the jquery instance of the app.js file?

Comment: Remove  `defer` from loading jquery script

Comment: Make sure the app.js script include is first.

Comment: Removed defer from the app.js file but that does not work either

Comment: Tey to load select2 lib locally

Comment: Did you find any solution. I am also struck with the same problem.